# blank space in multiple email addresses after ","

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, email-validation

I am using RegularExpressionValidator to validate multiple email addresses seprated by a comma "**,**"

My below expression works fine for this requirment:

```
"((\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)*([,])*)*"
```

Requirment is this expression should be able to handle space after comma in email addresses.

For example my current expression work file for email1@domain.com,email2@domain.com 
but what it do not do is email1@domain.com,  email2@domain.com

I understand there can be many solutions but in my snario best is to enhance this expression.

Please guide me

Comment: I can't answer your question, but I do want to point out that your regex [isn't optimal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion:

```
((\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)*([, ])*)*
```

That will accept blanks between the e-mail addresses

Comment: Thanks @Fischermaen, your suggestion worked. But can you please also guide why "((\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)*([,\s])*)*"

not work, I read \s indicate a space ? 

Please guide.

Comment: Inside the square brackets every character is interpreted as a character and `\s` will match a `\` and a `s` and not a  whitespace as you intended.

Answer (score 5):

You could use your existing regular expression and instead split the string by each comma and trim trailing/leading whitespace:

```
var emails = input.Split(',');
foreach (var email in emails.Select(ee => ee.Trim()))
{
    if (!emailValidator.IsMatch(email))
    {
        // announce a bad email
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides what Fischermaen said, another options could be to split emails into separate emails, and then validate each email separately.

```
   var emails = emailString.split(',');
   for(var i = 0; i < emails.length; i++){
      var email = emails[i].trim().replace(',', '');
      // Now you can validate a single, comma-less, space-less email;
   }
```